# python jsonschema validation using schema list

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I'm trying to validate a json file against a schema using python and jsonschema module. My schema is made up from a list of schemas, one of them has definitions of basic elements and the rest are collections of these elements and other objects.

I can't find the documentation for function which loads the list of schemas so that I can validate using it. I tried separating schemas into a dictionary and calling the appropriate one on a jsonObject, but that doesn't work since they cross reference each other.

How do I load/assemble all schemas into one for validation?

Part of the schema I'm trying to load:

```
[{
    "definitions": {
     "location": {
       "required": [
         "name",
         "country"
       ],
       "additionalProperties": false,
       "properties": {
         "country": {
           "pattern": "^[A-Z]{2}$",
           "type": "string"
         },
         "name": {
           "type": "string"
         }
       },
       "type": "object"
      }
    },
    "required": [
       "type",
       "content"
    ],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
     "content": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "type": "object"
     },
     "type": {
      "type": "string"
     }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "title": "base",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
  },
  {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "required": [
          "address"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "address": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/location"
        }
      },
      "type": {
        "pattern": "^person$"
      }
    }
  }]
```

And the json object would look something like this:

```
{
 "type":"person",
 "content":{
  "address": {
   "country": "US",
   "name" : "1,Street,City,State,US"
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only validate against one schema at a time, but that schema can reference (`$ref`) external schemas.  These references are usually URIs that can be used to GET the schema.  A filepath might work too if your schemas are not public.  Using a fixed up version of your example, this would look something like this ...

`http://your-domain.com/schema/person`

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Person",
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "http://your-domain.com/schema/base#" }],
  "properties": {
    "type": { "enum": ["person"] },
    "content": {
      "properties": {
        "address": { "$ref": "http://your-domain.com/schema/base#/definitions/location" }
      },
      "required": ["address"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

`http://your-domain.com/schema/base`

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "base",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "content": { "type": "object" },
    "type": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "required": ["type", "content"],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "definitions": {
    "location": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "country": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^[A-Z]{2}$"
        },
        "name": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["name", "country"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

Some documentation that might be useful

- https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validate/#the-validator-interface
- https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.org/en/latest/references/

Comment: Unfortunately the scheme is not set by me. Since it is used in many other areas, I can't change it and it's currently exists as a list. Is it possible to reference a scheme that exists as a variable inside the code (python)?

Comment: For the validator to reference an in-memory schema, you would have to build your own `RefResolver` that defines your custom behavior and plug it in to the validator.  The documentation I linked to should point you in the right direction.

Comment: As for validating based on a list of schemas, you simply can't do it.  It's just not a valid schema.  The best you can do is validate each schema independently and ensure that none fail.  However, these two schema will never both validate because of the use of `additionalProperties` in the `content` property.  One requires the object to be empty while the other requires the object to have a `address` property.  These are mutually exclusive conditions.

Comment: If this list of schemas is being used in many other areas, can you see how it is being used in those cases and do something similar?

Comment: Yeah, I ended up asking the guy who wrote and he said that I will just to have to write a function which will construct a single scheme from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hand coding a single schema from all your schemata, you can create a small schema which *refers* to the other schema files.  This way you can use multiple existing JSONschema files and validate against them in combination:

```
import yaml
import jsonschema

A_yaml = """
id: http://foo/a.json
type: object
properties: 
    prop: 
        $ref: "./num_string.json"
"""

num_string_yaml = """
id: http://foo/num_string.json
type: string
pattern: ^[0-9]*$
"""

A = yaml.load(A_yaml)
num_string = yaml.load(num_string_yaml)

resolver = jsonschema.RefResolver("",None,
        store={
            "http://foo/A.json":A,
            "http://foo/num_string.json":num_string,
            })

validator = jsonschema.Draft4Validator(
        A, resolver=resolver)

try:
    validator.validate({"prop":"1234"})
    print "Properly accepted object"
except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 
    print "Failed to accept object"

try:
    validator.validate({"prop":"12d34"})
    print "Failed to reject object"
except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 
    print "Properly rejected object"
```

Note that you may want to combine the external using one of the schema cominators `oneOf`, `allOf`, or `anyOf` to combine your schemata like so:

```
[A.yaml]
oneOf:
     - $ref: "sub-schema1.json"
     - $ref: "sub-schema2.json"
     - $ref: "sub-schema3.json"
```